# Different continious color bars for different classes in Python

Tags: python, plot, colors, plotly, colorbar

I have data points that belong to three different classes. On the other hand, I have weight for each data point in its class. I want to color my points based on their weight, but with three different continuous range of colors. Actually I want something like the following image (which is made by hand). Now I'm using Plotly for coloring, but any other method compatible with python is welcomed.

[image]

Actually I want to combine the two output of the code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n_data = 100
n_class = 3
t1 = [random.random() for i in range(n_data)]
t2 = [random.random() for i in range(n_data)]
class_color = [str(random.randint(1,n_class)) for i in range(n_data)]
weight_color = [random.random() for i in range(n_data)]
df = pd.DataFrame()
print(len(t1))
print(len(t2))
df['x'] = t1
df['y'] = t2
df['class_color'] = class_color
df['weight_color'] = weight_color
fig1 = px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y", color="class_color")
fig1.show()

fig2 = px.scatter(df, x="x", y="y", color="weight_color")
fig2.show()
```

Comment: Do you mind to add a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

Please don't take it as an answer (yet). As far as I can see you can use different color scales with plotly. But you should work on how properly show all legends

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
dfs = [d[1] for d in list(df.groupby('species'))]

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=dfs[0]["sepal_width"],
               y=dfs[0]["sepal_length"],mode="markers",
               marker=dict(color=dfs[0]["sepal_length"],
                           colorscale='Viridis',
                           showscale=True),
               name=dfs[0]["species"].unique()[0],
               showlegend=False
               ))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=dfs[1]["sepal_width"],
               y=dfs[1]["sepal_length"],mode="markers",
               marker=dict(color=dfs[1]["sepal_length"],
                           colorscale='Magenta',
                           showscale=False),
               name=dfs[1]["species"].unique()[0],
               showlegend=False
               ))


fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=dfs[2]["sepal_width"],
               y=dfs[2]["sepal_length"],mode="markers",
               marker=dict(color=dfs[2]["sepal_length"],
                           colorscale='Cividis',
                           showscale=False),
               name=dfs[2]["species"].unique()[0],
               showlegend=False
               ))
```

[image]